# How can I send an array from a ViewController File to a Swift File (with no view controller)?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have looked at questions like this one, but they are not the same or I can't get a clear answer.

I have one array,

```
var numbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

located in a file attached to a view controller called `numbers.swift`. In a different file, a swift file that is not connected to any view controller called `numbersTwo.swift` has an array with nothing in it. How can I send `numbers` from `numbers.swift` to `numbersTwo.swift` and replace the array in the file?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You need to show more relevant code in your question.

Comment: You have misunderstood the basics of object oriented developing. I suggest you read up on what it means. Nothing is based on what file they're in. Don't think of them like **files**. In the files - there should be `classes`. Create a link to a class (from another file) in the first class (the other file). You need to do some more research.

Comment: Try `let arr2 = numbersClass().numbers.map { $0 }`, where `arr2` lies in `numbersTwo.swift` and `numbersClass` is class name in `numbers.swift`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the `NumbersTwo.Swift` file as a Singleton.

Read here: [Apple -Singleton](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID177)

Numbers ViewController:

```
class Numbers: ViewController{

    var numbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

    let numbersTwo = NumbersTwo.sharedInstance

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        numbersTwo.emptyArray.append(contentsOf: numbers)
    }
}
```

NumbersTwo Swift file:

```
class NumbersTwo{

    static let sharedInstance = NumbersTwo()

    var emptyArray = [String]() // this will no longer be empty
}
```

Comment: Really big help!

Comment: glad to have helped! :)

Comment: Btw the first letter in Class names should always be capitalized. You used lowercase in your question.